# finding combinations multiple rows excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the data that looks like the following in excel:

```
Ingredient1  Ingredient2  Ingredient3  Ingredient 4
Salami       Tuna         Peperoni     Mushroom
Salami       Peperoni     Mushroom
Salami       Mushroom
```

Ingredients are the column names and some cells are empty because there are not enough ingredients.

I would like to get the combinations and the count, for example:

```
Salami, Tuna      1 
Salami, Peperoni  2
Salami, Mushroom  3
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Salami, Tuna 1? correct?

Comment: You can achieve this by just using a `COUNTIF` or `COUNTIFS` if 'Salami' changes as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bit. You can give this a go if you like. It will need modifying for your specific inputs and outputs but it works. It will combine the first column with each individual ingredient and count. i.e. It won't return combinations like 'Mushroom, Pepperoni' but that wasn't what you specified in your question

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CountDemo()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c
    Dim Ing As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim key
    '' Set up for dictionary object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    '' Declare data range
    With Sheet1
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 4))
    End With

    '' Loop through each c in range
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        '' Test if cell is null
        If Not c.Value2 = vbNullString Then
            '' Set Ingredient combo to variable
            Ing = c.Offset(0, 1 - c.Column).Value2 & ", " & c.Value2
            '' Test if value exists in dictionary
            If dict.exists(Ing) Then
                '' If exists increase count by 1
                dict(Ing) = dict(Ing) + 1
            Else
                '' If doesn't exist then add to dictionary and set to default value of 1
                dict.Add key:=Ing, Item:=1
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    '' Output results
    'Starting row
    i = 8
    '' Loop through each ingredient combo
    For Each key In dict.keys
        '' Print to sheet values
        With Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
            .Value2 = key
            .Offset(0, 1).Value2 = dict(key)
        End With
        i = i + 1
    Next key
End Sub
```